# Creating a reusable Reader class in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics

I'm making a small learning project. In it i'm reading some JSON from a restservice and persisting it in a postgres DB. The restservice has several JSON models that are available from different URL's. I have created a simple reader class that reads the JSON from a url and sends it to the DB. This works with the Model and Service classes hardcoded in the Reader class. I am trying to make it more generic however so i can use the reader class and pass in the model class and service class (that has an add method that calls the save method form the repository for that Model). I tried this with the models implementing an interface and having the interface as parameter in the constructor of the reader class or passing the model classname as a string to the Reader constructor and it being a parameter for a Classloader.
I haven't gotten it to work and probably it is a silly syntax problem  but maybe somebody here can help out. Below are the classes:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Reader {

    private MapService mapService;

    public void readStream(String url) {

        try (InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream()) {

            JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

            reader.beginArray();
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                MapInputModel map = gson.fromJson(reader, MapInputModel.class);

                mapService.add(map);
            }

            reader.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            log.error("MalformedURLException" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("IOException" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class MapService {

    private final MapModelMapper mapModelMapper;
    private final MapEntityRepository mapEntityRepository;

    public void add(final MapInputModel mapInputModel) {
        mapEntityRepository.save(mapModelMapper.toEntity(mapInputModel));
    }
```

.

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MapInputModel {

    private String name;
    private List<String> translations;
}
```

The Mapservice and MapInputModel need to be replaceable with similar classes, like:

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class IconModel {

    Map<String, String> icon;

}
```

I'm using SpringBoot and Lombok in this project.

-------- edit: updated classmodels ---------

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MapInputModel implements InputModel {

    private String name;
    private List<String> translations;
}

public interface IService<T>{

    void add(final T model);
}


@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class MapService implements IService<MapInputModel> {

    private final MapModelMapper mapModelMapper;
    private final MapEntityRepository mapEntityRepository;

    @Override
    public void add(final MapInputModel mapInputModel) {
        mapEntityRepository.save(mapModelMapper.toEntity(mapInputModel));
    }

}

@Slf4j
public class Reader {

    private IService<InputModel> service;
    private InputModel model;

    public Reader(IService<InputModel> service, InputModel model) {
        this.service = service;
        this.model = model;
    }
    // code
}
```

Comment: *I haven't gotten it to work and probably it is a silly syntax problem*. Are you getting an error/exception?

Comment: I posted some updates in the original post. In two classes I implemented an interface. I tried to put the interface in the constructor of the Reader class so I could instantiate it with the correct classes that I would need for the Reader object at that moment (and could instantiate it in another case with, for example, the Icon classe(s). This doesnt really work however. I can't get a correct Reader instance. 
I tried it with:
 reader = new Reader(mapService<MapInputModel.class>, MapInputModel.class);
But that isnt correct. Not sure if the constructor is okay or if that one is wrong too,